# Javamail attachments data lost

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I use Javamail to save attachments in a temp Folder, code is given below :-

```
for (int i = 0; i < multipartmsg.getCount(); ++i) {

    BodyPart bodypart = multipartmsg.getBodyPart(i);
              if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodypart.getDisposition())
                && null != bodypart.getFileName()
                    && !bodypart.getFileName().isEmpty()) {

            InputStream is = bodypart.getInputStream();
            MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart(is);
            File f = new File("/temp/"+abcd);

            mbp.saveFile(f);
    }
```

But a 250kB file gets saved as 220kB. There is a loss of data, hence I am unable to open the file. Any idea why this may be happening ?

I also set my **properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");** since I use imaps to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you creating a new MimeBodyPart with the content of the original part?  That makes no sense, and is likely the source of your problem.  Just use the saveFile method on the original part.

Comment: I realize that it was silly of me to first create a bodypart and then a mimebodypart over that, to use saveFile() method, when a simple cast could have done work. Yes, this was the cause of my problem. Thanks :)